# f# console app doesn't work. c# console app does

Tags: c#, f#, console

I am attempting to deploy a simple f# console app to a coworkers computer but it keeps failing. After double clicking on the app icon, the console window appears but then the Microsoft error reporting window shows up asking if I would like to send the error report, I decline then some text flashes in the console window. It looks like an error message, but the window closes too fast to tell. The weird thing is, if I create a similar C# app, it works. I am targeting .net 4 client framework in release mode.

Here is the code

f# code (doesn't work):

```ml
open System

printfn "print test"
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

c# code (does work):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestCApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it from an existing console window and read the error.

Comment: @SLaks. Good call, I didn't think of it. I'll try it.

Comment: Your code requires presence of FSharp.Core libraries on the target computer. Do they present there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the references of your F# project and you will see one to FSharp.Core which is normally located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll

On Windows 7 (64 bit) PC

Also look at the F# site to get the runtime download.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/release.aspx

EDIT: here is the direct link to the runtime download (thanks  ildjarn):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13450

Comment: There's no link to the F# redist from that page. Direct link is [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=186910).

Comment: If you don't want to make everyone install the F# runtime, just set the FSharp.Core reference to `Copy Local: true` and it will show up in the output directory next to your executable. Just copy both files together.

Answer (score 8):

The F# analog of your C# snippet would be not your F# code, but the following:

```
System.Console.WriteLine "print test"
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

While the app off 2-liner above will run, similarly to one off your C# snippet, just on raw .NET, use of `printfn` function in your F# code requires certain F#-specific core components being deployed on the target computer, which is likely not the case. The latter explains the observed behavior.